# configure rte to enable my own classes for links

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, rte

I have a configuration for an TYPO3 installation to use individual styles for multiple kinds of links in the RTE. If I use these styles by hand (insert them in "toggle"-mode) all is well. But trying to use them in the link-wizard result in chaos as some styles are available, some styles are not available.

my RTE-config as it is included from the root-page (extract with only the link-classes):

RTE {

```
    default {
        contentCSS.rte = EXT:my_site/Resources/Public/Css/rte.css

        allowedClasses := addToList(link-int,link-ext,link-mail,link-tel,link-mobile,link-file,link-no-icon)

        proc {
            allowTags = a, abbr, article, b, bdo, big, blockquote, br, caption, center, cite, code, div, em, footer, header, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, i, li, link, nav, ol, p, pre, section, small, span, strike, strong, sub, sup, table, thead, tbody, tfoot, td, th, tr, u, ul
        }
        showButtons = ...
        toolbarOrder = ...
        defaultContentLanguage = de
        buttons {
            textstyle {
                tags.a.allowedClasses := addtoList(link-int,link-ext,link-mail,link-tel,link-mobile,link-no-icon,link-file)
                showTagFreeClasses = 1
            }

            link.properties.class.allowedClasses := addToList(link-int,link-ext,link-mail,link-tel,link-mobile,link-no-icon,link-file)

}
        rteResize = 1
    }

    classes {

        link-int.name = interner Link
        link-ext.name = externer Link
        link-mail.name = Mail Link
        link-tel.name = Telefon Link
        link-mobile.name = Handy Link
        link-file.name = Datei Link
        link-no-icon.name = ohne Icon
        download.name = automatische download klasse?
        mail.name = automatische mail klasse?
    }

    proc {
        // Keep unknown tags
        dontRemoveUnknownTags_db = 1

        // Allow tables
        preserveTables = 1

        entryHTMLparser_db = 1
        entryHTMLparser_db {

            // Tags allowed
            allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags

            // HTML special characters
            htmlSpecialChars = 0

            // Additionnal attributes for P & DIV
            tags.div.allowedAttribs = class,style,align
            tags.p.allowedAttribs = class,style,align

            // Keep non matched tags
            keepNonMatchedTags = protect
        }

        // Exit HTML parser
        exitHTMLparser_db = 1
        exitHTMLparser_db {
            // Keep non matched tags
            keepNonMatchedTags = 1

            // HTML special character
            htmlSpecialChars = 0
        }
    }
    classesAnchor {
        // in case of old styles: 
        externalLink {
            class = link-ext
        }
        externalLinkInNewWindow {
            class = link-ext
        }
        internalLink {
            class = link-int
        }
        internalLinkInNewWindow {
            class = link-int
        }
        download {
            class = link-file
        }
        mail {
            class = link-mail
        }
    }

    default.proc.allowedClasses < .default.allowedClasses

    default.FE >
    default.FE < .default
}
```

the strange thing: 
these classes appear and work well:

- externer Link (link-ext)
- Telefon Link  (link-tel)
- Handy link (link-mobile)
- ohne icon (link-no-icon

these classes are not available in the dropdowns of the wizard:

- interner Link (link-int)
- Datei Link (link-file)

in the mentioned rte.css is this block (the real styling appears in the global CSS)

```
a.link-file {}
a.link-int {}
a.link-ext {}
a.link-mail {}
a.link-tel {}
a.link-mobile {}
a.link-no-icon {}
```

why are those two classes missing? 
how to remove or replace the build-in classes?